# Unable to load CoreML model using MLModel.compileModel(at:)

Tags: swift, file, coreml

I am trying to load a `.mlmodel` file using the following code:

```
let paths =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)
var documentsUrl = paths[0]
documentsUrl.appendPathComponent("parallel.mlmodel")
do {
    let compiledModelUrl = try MLModel.compileModel(at: documentsUrl)
    let model = try? MLModel(contentsOf: compiledModelUrl)
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

But I get the error `The file couldn’t be saved.`, the model does exist at that location.

Comment: Need a bit more info: Where did you get the mlmodel file from? What iOS version does this run on? Which of the lines gives that error message? What else is in the error message?

Comment: This is on OSX, the error occurs on the line `let compiledModelUrl = try MLModel.compileModel(at: documentsUrl)`, that's the entire error message. I generated the mlmodel myself using Keras.

Comment: Does it work when you add the mlmodel directly to the Xcode project?

Comment: How do I reference that file if the mlmodel is imported to the project?

Comment: You don't need to. You would use the class that Xcode automatically generates. The model is already compiled now inside your app bundle.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. I also encountered this problem when I deploy an app to an iphone from Mac in debug mode. Actually, there is nothing wrong with the code, it is something else. I did two things, first signed in to icloud (does icloud have anything to do with its provisioning profile for development?), secondly delete the app and re-deploy the app to the iphone. It solves the problem now. 
Although I am not sure which one solves my problem, I assume it is the second thing I did. Let me know if anyone found the reason behind.

See my original post.
[Unable to load CoreML model using MLModel.compileModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56895366/unable-to-load-coreml-model-using-mlmodel-compilemodel/56906171#56906171)