# Unable to load CoreML model using MLModel.compileModel

Tags: coreml

The `CoreML` couldn't be loaded. The first line is successful, but the second line gives an error called: The file couldn’t be saved. 
The model does exist and `modelUrl` is correct.
The same issue is also found here
[Unable to load CoreML model using MLModel.compileModel(at:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53852591/unable-to-load-coreml-model-using-mlmodel-compilemodelat/56895307#56895307)

Does someone know what the cause is?

```
var modelUrl = NSBundle.MainBundle.GetUrlForResource("SentimentPolarity", "mlmodel");
var compiledModelUrl = MLModel.CompileModel(modelUrl, out var error);
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer just now. I encountered this problem when I deploy an app to an iphone from Mac in debug mode. Actually, there is nothing wrong with the code, it is something else. I did two things, first sign in to icloud(does icloud have anything to do with the iphone's provisioning profile for development?), secondly delete the app and re-deploy the app to the iphone. It solves the problem now. 
Although I am not sure which one solves my problem, I assume it is the second thing I did. Let me know if anyone found the reason behind.